# I want to server my iFrame content to another server (cross-domain)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, iframe, apache2, cross-domain

I'm wondering if anyone could enlighten me on what Apache or HTML settings affect the ability of an iframe to load content from a different domain. I'm not trying to communicate between the two domains, just simply load some HTML, but I can't, and I'm not sure why. I suspect some Apache configuration, but I'm not sure.

To clarify, I'm controlling the server and content on domain A, which needs to allow domain B to load it's content...

Also, I notice this error in my Safari log:

`Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

I'm using Rails 4, Apache2.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add to my Rails Application config the following line:

`config.action_dispatch.default_headers['X-Frame-Options'] = "GOFORIT"`